# How to use ubifs image with modprobe? To extract ubifs image

Tags: kernel-modules, image-manipulation, modprobe, dump, ubifs

I try to do something like this - [link](https://github.com/nlitsme/ubidump/).

All examples in the web are not working at all.

```
modprobe ubi mtd=0
modprobe: module ubi not found in modules.dep

modprobe ubi
modprobe: module ubi not found in modules.dep

modprobe ubi mtd=/dev/mtd0
modprobe: module ubi not found in modules.dep
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should ensure that your module is exists in module directories. For example:

```
find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name 'ubi.ko'
```

If your module doesn't exist you need to build it.

Secondly, your output `module ubi not found in modules.dep` tells to you that there is no info about module in `modules.dep` ([man 5 modules.dep](https://linux.die.net/man/5/modules.dep)).

You need to call `depmod` ([man 8 depmod](https://linux.die.net/man/8/depmod)) to complete info about module dependencies.